# api endpoint giving undefined

Tags: javascript, rest

I m trying to make a call to shorturl API which fulfills the promise but when I console.log the result and next then, it says undefined.

following is my code

```
const handleCall = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
     fetch(`https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=www.udemy.com`)
     .then(res =>  console.log( res.json()))
     .then(res => console.log(res))

}
```

Comment: the first then should return the promise with the result so that the second one 
can use the chain then

Answer (score 1):

You never `await` your `res.json()` when you wrap it inside the `console.log` because it doesn't return a promise anymore. So just remove the `console.log`:

```js
const handleCall = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(`https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=www.udemy.com`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

➔ yields: `{ok: true, result: {…}}`

---

There is no need in logging it twice because it will be the same output. If you really want to log it in both functions, await it and then return it:

```js
const handleCall = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(`https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=www.udemy.com`)
        .then(async res => {
            let x = await res.json();
            console.log(x);
            return x;
         })
        .then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

➔ yields: `{ok: true, result: {…}}` `{ok: true, result: {…}}`